# react-native trigger enter key press in afterSearch when the user stops typing

Tags: react-native, keypress

I am using the following search box:

https://github.com/agiletechvn/react-native-search-box/

to load the contacts list page but there are a few nested API calls retrieving data based on what the user has typed.

In my experience the results being loaded onChangeText as opposed to them being loaded on onAfterSearch and pressing the enter key is more seamless and smooth

How can I trigger the click event on the enter key manually from the code to load the view?